# Cambiar border-radious desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas, como podréis ver si ejecutáis el programa, se trata de un texto en el cual podemos modificar básicamente el color, texto, etc. No obstante, el añadir border radious y poner espacio entre palabras no funciona. Puede ser que la referencia del CSS en JS este mal, ya que no se nombran igual al no tener - Ejemplo:(`font-size, fontSize`)

## HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="DH16.js"></script>
  <link rel="StyleSheet" href="DH16.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <p id="principal">
     Modifique este texto a su gusto
  </p>
   <br>
   <br>
   Color de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarColorFuente()" id="colorfuente">
     <option value="#000000">Negro</option>
     <option value="#ff0000">Rojo</option>
     <option value="#00ff00">Verde</option>
     <option value="#0000ff">Azul</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Color de fondo:
   <select onChange="cambiarColorDeFondo()" id="colorfondo">
     <option value="#ffff00">Amarillo</option>
     <option value="#ff0000">Rojo</option>
     <option value="#00ff00">Verde</option>
     <option value="#0000ff">Azul</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Tamaño de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarTamano()" id="cambiartamano">
     <option value="1px">1px</option>
     <option value="5px">5px</option>
     <option value="10px">10px</option>
     <option value="15px">15px</option>
     <option value="20px">20px</option>
     <option value="30px">30px</option>
     <option value="40px">40px</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Tipo de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarFuente()" id="cambiarfuente">
     <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
     <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
     <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Estilo de fuente:
   <select onChange="estiloDeFuente()" id="estilofuente">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="Oblique">Oblique</option>
     <option value="Italic">Italic</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Alineacion de texto:
   <select onChange="alineacion()" id="alineacion">
     <option value="center">Centrado</option>
     <option value="right">Derecha</option>
     <option value="left">Izquierda</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Decoracion de texto:
   <select onChange="decoracion()" id="decoracion">
     <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
     <option value="underline">Subrallado</option>
     <option value="overline">Subrallado superior</option>
     <option value="line-through">Tachado</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Peso de la fuente:
   <select onChange="pesoFuente()" id="peso">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="bold">Negrita</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Espacio entre palabras:
   <select onChange="espacioPalabras()" id="ep">
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Transformacion de texto:
   <select onChange="transformacionTexto()" id="transformacion">
     <option value="uppercase">Mayusculas</option>
     <option value="lowercase">Minusculas</option>
     <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Ancho del borde:
   <select Onchange="anchoDeBorde()" id="anchoborde">
     <option value="0px">0</option>
     <option value="1px">1</option>
     <option value="2px">2</option>
     <option value="3px">3</option>
     <option value="4px">4</option>
     <option value="5px">5</option>
     <option value="6px">6</option>
     <option value="7px">7</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Estilo de borde:
<select onChange="cambiarEstiloBorde()" id="estiloborde">
<option value="none">none</option>
<option value="hidden">hidden</option>
<option value="dotted">dotted</option>
<option value="dashed">dashed</option>
<option value="solid">solid</option>
<option value="double">double</option>
<option value="groove">groove</option>
<option value="ridge">ridge</option>
<option value="inset">inset</option>
<option value="outset">outset</option>
</select>
<br>
Color de borde:
<select onChange="cambiarColorBorde()" id="colorborde">
<option value="#000000">negro</option>
<option value="#ffff00">amarillo</option>
<option value="#ff0000">rojo</option>
<option value="#00ff00">verde</option>
<option value="#0000ff">azul</option>
</select>
<br>
padding:
<select onChange="cambiarPadding()" id="padding">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<br>
margin:
<select onChange="cambiarMargin()" id="margin">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<br>
Bordeado redondo:
<select onChange="borderRadious()" id="radious">
  <option value="0px">0</option>
  <option value="1px">1</option>
  <option value="2px">2</option>
  <option value="3px">3</option>

</body>
</html>
```

## JavaScript

```
function cambiarColorFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cf=document.getElementById('colorfuente');
  principal.style.color=cf.value;
}

function cambiarColorDeFondo(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cdf=document.getElementById('colorfondo');
  principal.style.backgroundColor=cdf.value;
}

function cambiarTamano(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ct=document.getElementById('cambiartamano');
  principal.style.fontSize=ct.value;
}

function cambiarFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cff=document.getElementById('cambiarfuente');
  principal.style.fontFamily=cff.value;
}

function estiloDeFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var edf=document.getElementById('estilofuente');
  principal.style.fontStyle=edf.value;
}

function alineacion(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var a=document.getElementById('alineacion');
  principal.style.textAlign=a.value;
}

function decoracion(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var d=document.getElementById('decoracion');
  principal.style.textDecoration=d.value;
}

function pesoFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var p=document.getElementById('peso');
  principal.style.fontWeight=p.value;
}

function espacioPalabras(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ep=document.getElementById('ep');
  principal.style.wordSpacing=ep.value;
}

function transformacionTexto(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var t=document.getElementById('transformacion');
  principal.style.textTransform=t.value;
}

function anchoDeBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var adb=document.getElementById('anchoborde');
  principal.style.borderWidth=adb.value;
}

function cambiarEstiloBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ceb=document.getElementById('estiloborde');
  principal.style.borderStyle=ceb.value;
}

function cambiarColorBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ccb=document.getElementById('colorborde');
  principal.style.borderColor=ccb.value;
}

function cambiarPadding(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cp=document.getElementById('padding');
  principal.style.padding=cp.value;
}

function cambiarMargin(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cm=document.getElementById('margin');
  principal.style.margin=cm.value;
}

function borderRadious(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var br=document.getElementById('radious');
  principal.style.borderRadious=br.value;
}
```

### CSS

```
#principal {
  font-size:15px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te faltaba agregar `px` en algunas partes del código y en el `js` es `borderRadius`, y tu escribes `borderRadious`
he aquí el código ya modificado:
**JS**

```
function cambiarColorFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cf=document.getElementById('colorfuente');
  principal.style.color=cf.value;
}

function cambiarColorDeFondo(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cdf=document.getElementById('colorfondo');
  principal.style.backgroundColor=cdf.value;
}

function cambiarTamano(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ct=document.getElementById('cambiartamano');
  principal.style.fontSize=ct.value;
}

function cambiarFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cff=document.getElementById('cambiarfuente');
  principal.style.fontFamily=cff.value;
}

function estiloDeFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var edf=document.getElementById('estilofuente');
  principal.style.fontStyle=edf.value;
}

function alineacion(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var a=document.getElementById('alineacion');
  principal.style.textAlign=a.value;
}

function decoracion(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var d=document.getElementById('decoracion');
  principal.style.textDecoration=d.value;
}

function pesoFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var p=document.getElementById('peso');
  principal.style.fontWeight=p.value;
}

function espacioPalabras(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ep=document.getElementById('ep');
  principal.style.wordSpacing=ep.value;
}

function transformacionTexto(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var t=document.getElementById('transformacion');
  principal.style.textTransform=t.value;
}

function anchoDeBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var adb=document.getElementById('anchoborde');
  principal.style.borderWidth=adb.value;
}

function cambiarEstiloBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ceb=document.getElementById('estiloborde');
  principal.style.borderStyle=ceb.value;
}

function cambiarColorBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ccb=document.getElementById('colorborde');
  principal.style.borderColor=ccb.value;
}

function cambiarPadding(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cp=document.getElementById('padding');
  principal.style.padding=cp.value;
}

function cambiarMargin(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cm=document.getElementById('margin');
  principal.style.margin=cm.value;
}

function borderRadious(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var br=document.getElementById('radious');
  principal.style.borderRadius=br.value;
}
```

**Y el html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <p id="principal">
     Modifique este texto a su gusto
  </p>
   <br>
   <br>
   Color de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarColorFuente()" id="colorfuente">
     <option value="#000000">Negro</option>
     <option value="#ff0000">Rojo</option>
     <option value="#00ff00">Verde</option>
     <option value="#0000ff">Azul</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Color de fondo:
   <select onChange="cambiarColorDeFondo()" id="colorfondo">
     <option value="#ffff00">Amarillo</option>
     <option value="#ff0000">Rojo</option>
     <option value="#00ff00">Verde</option>
     <option value="#0000ff">Azul</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Tamaño de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarTamano()" id="cambiartamano">
     <option value="1px">1px</option>
     <option value="5px">5px</option>
     <option value="10px">10px</option>
     <option value="15px">15px</option>
     <option value="20px">20px</option>
     <option value="30px">30px</option>
     <option value="40px">40px</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Tipo de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarFuente()" id="cambiarfuente">
     <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
     <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
     <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Estilo de fuente:
   <select onChange="estiloDeFuente()" id="estilofuente">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="Oblique">Oblique</option>
     <option value="Italic">Italic</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Alineacion de texto:
   <select onChange="alineacion()" id="alineacion">
     <option value="center">Centrado</option>
     <option value="right">Derecha</option>
     <option value="left">Izquierda</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Decoracion de texto:
   <select onChange="decoracion()" id="decoracion">
     <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
     <option value="underline">Subrallado</option>
     <option value="overline">Subrallado superior</option>
     <option value="line-through">Tachado</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Peso de la fuente:
   <select onChange="pesoFuente()" id="peso">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="bold">Negrita</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Espacio entre palabras:
   <select onChange="espacioPalabras()" id="ep">
     <option value="3px">3</option>
     <option value="6px">6</option>
     <option value="9px">9</option>
     <option value="12px">12</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Transformacion de texto:
   <select onChange="transformacionTexto()" id="transformacion">
     <option value="uppercase">Mayusculas</option>
     <option value="lowercase">Minusculas</option>
     <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Ancho del borde:
   <select Onchange="anchoDeBorde()" id="anchoborde">
     <option value="0px">0</option>
     <option value="1px">1</option>
     <option value="2px">2</option>
     <option value="3px">3</option>
     <option value="4px">4</option>
     <option value="5px">5</option>
     <option value="6px">6</option>
     <option value="7px">7</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Estilo de borde:
<select onChange="cambiarEstiloBorde()" id="estiloborde">
<option value="none">none</option>
<option value="hidden">hidden</option>
<option value="dotted">dotted</option>
<option value="dashed">dashed</option>
<option value="solid">solid</option>
<option value="double">double</option>
<option value="groove">groove</option>
<option value="ridge">ridge</option>
<option value="inset">inset</option>
<option value="outset">outset</option>
</select>
<br>
Color de borde:
<select onChange="cambiarColorBorde()" id="colorborde">
<option value="#000000">negro</option>
<option value="#ffff00">amarillo</option>
<option value="#ff0000">rojo</option>
<option value="#00ff00">verde</option>
<option value="#0000ff">azul</option>
</select>
<br>
padding:
<select onChange="cambiarPadding()" id="padding">
<option value="0px">0</option>
<option value="4px" selected="selected">4</option>
<option value="8px">8</option>
<option value="12px">12</option>
<option value="16px">16</option>
<option value="20px">20</option>
</select>
<br>
margin:
<select onChange="cambiarMargin()" id="margin">
<option value="0px">0</option>
<option value="4px" selected="selected">4</option>
<option value="8px">8</option>
<option value="12px">12</option>
<option value="16px">16</option>
<option value="20px">20</option>
</select>
<br>
Bordeado redondo:
<select onChange="borderRadious()" id="radious">
  <option value="0px">0</option>
  <option value="1px">1</option>
  <option value="2px">2</option>
  <option value="3px">3</option>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva saludos

Comment: @Vendetta `wordSpacing` es espacio entre palabras y funciona en el ejemplo, para crear un espacio entre las letra usa `letterSpacing = "5px"` por ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Escribiste el nombre mal. En vez de `borderRadious` deberia de ser `borderRadius`(sin la o). y tienes que especificarle `px` a wordSpacing.

```js
function cambiarColorFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cf=document.getElementById('colorfuente');
  principal.style.color=cf.value;
}

function cambiarColorDeFondo(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cdf=document.getElementById('colorfondo');
  principal.style.backgroundColor=cdf.value;
}

function cambiarTamano(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ct=document.getElementById('cambiartamano');
  principal.style.fontSize=ct.value;
}

function cambiarFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cff=document.getElementById('cambiarfuente');
  principal.style.fontFamily=cff.value;
}

function estiloDeFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var edf=document.getElementById('estilofuente');
  principal.style.fontStyle=edf.value;
}

function alineacion(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var a=document.getElementById('alineacion');
  principal.style.textAlign=a.value;
}

function decoracion(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var d=document.getElementById('decoracion');
  principal.style.textDecoration=d.value;
}

function pesoFuente(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var p=document.getElementById('peso');
  principal.style.fontWeight=p.value;
}

function espacioPalabras(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ep=document.getElementById('ep');
  principal.style.wordSpacing=ep.value + "px";
}

function transformacionTexto(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var t=document.getElementById('transformacion');
  principal.style.textTransform=t.value;
}

function anchoDeBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var adb=document.getElementById('anchoborde');
  principal.style.borderWidth=adb.value;
}

function cambiarEstiloBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ceb=document.getElementById('estiloborde');
  principal.style.borderStyle=ceb.value;
}

function cambiarColorBorde(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var ccb=document.getElementById('colorborde');
  principal.style.borderColor=ccb.value;
}

function cambiarPadding(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cp=document.getElementById('padding');
  principal.style.padding=cp.value;
}

function cambiarMargin(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var cm=document.getElementById('margin');
  principal.style.margin=cm.value;
}

function borderRadious(){
  var principal=document.getElementById('principal');
  var br=document.getElementById('radious');
  principal.style.borderRadius=br.value;
}
```

```css
#principal {
  font-size:15px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="DH16.js"></script>
  <link rel="StyleSheet" href="DH16.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <p id="principal">
     Modifique este texto a su gusto
  </p>
   <br>
   <br>
   Color de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarColorFuente()" id="colorfuente">
     <option value="#000000">Negro</option>
     <option value="#ff0000">Rojo</option>
     <option value="#00ff00">Verde</option>
     <option value="#0000ff">Azul</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Color de fondo:
   <select onChange="cambiarColorDeFondo()" id="colorfondo">
     <option value="#ffff00">Amarillo</option>
     <option value="#ff0000">Rojo</option>
     <option value="#00ff00">Verde</option>
     <option value="#0000ff">Azul</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Tamaño de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarTamano()" id="cambiartamano">
     <option value="1px">1px</option>
     <option value="5px">5px</option>
     <option value="10px">10px</option>
     <option value="15px">15px</option>
     <option value="20px">20px</option>
     <option value="30px">30px</option>
     <option value="40px">40px</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Tipo de fuente:
   <select onChange="cambiarFuente()" id="cambiarfuente">
     <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
     <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
     <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Estilo de fuente:
   <select onChange="estiloDeFuente()" id="estilofuente">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="Oblique">Oblique</option>
     <option value="Italic">Italic</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Alineacion de texto:
   <select onChange="alineacion()" id="alineacion">
     <option value="center">Centrado</option>
     <option value="right">Derecha</option>
     <option value="left">Izquierda</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Decoracion de texto:
   <select onChange="decoracion()" id="decoracion">
     <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
     <option value="underline">Subrallado</option>
     <option value="overline">Subrallado superior</option>
     <option value="line-through">Tachado</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Peso de la fuente:
   <select onChange="pesoFuente()" id="peso">
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="bold">Negrita</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Espacio entre palabras:
   <select onChange="espacioPalabras()" id="ep">
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Transformacion de texto:
   <select onChange="transformacionTexto()" id="transformacion">
     <option value="uppercase">Mayusculas</option>
     <option value="lowercase">Minusculas</option>
     <option value="none">Ninguno</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Ancho del borde:
   <select Onchange="anchoDeBorde()" id="anchoborde">
     <option value="0px">0</option>
     <option value="1px">1</option>
     <option value="2px">2</option>
     <option value="3px">3</option>
     <option value="4px">4</option>
     <option value="5px">5</option>
     <option value="6px">6</option>
     <option value="7px">7</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   Estilo de borde:
<select onChange="cambiarEstiloBorde()" id="estiloborde">
<option value="none">none</option>
<option value="hidden">hidden</option>
<option value="dotted">dotted</option>
<option value="dashed">dashed</option>
<option value="solid">solid</option>
<option value="double">double</option>
<option value="groove">groove</option>
<option value="ridge">ridge</option>
<option value="inset">inset</option>
<option value="outset">outset</option>
</select>
<br>
Color de borde:
<select onChange="cambiarColorBorde()" id="colorborde">
<option value="#000000">negro</option>
<option value="#ffff00">amarillo</option>
<option value="#ff0000">rojo</option>
<option value="#00ff00">verde</option>
<option value="#0000ff">azul</option>
</select>
<br>
padding:
<select onChange="cambiarPadding()" id="padding">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<br>
margin:
<select onChange="cambiarMargin()" id="margin">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<br>
Bordeado redondo:
<select onChange="borderRadious()" id="radious">
  <option value="0px">0</option>
  <option value="1px">1</option>
  <option value="2px">2</option>
  <option value="3px">3</option>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar esto:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property = nuevo estilo
```

por ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
```

Comment: Ese puede ser un método, pero lo que realmente quiero saber es como seria con border radious y wordspacing. Es decir : document.getElementById("p2").style.(borderRadious??)=3px;